# Google translate API with synonyms

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I am using Google translate API in my iOS app. But to get the best fit translation for my words, I need to get synonyms of translated word like it present on Google Translate web page.

I have found some libraries which provide synonyms but all works with English words only.

Is there any Google API which we can use with google translate api to get synonyms of translated word in target language.

Answer (score 5):

The Google Translation API service doesn't support the **multiple translations of a word** functionality. This feature is only available via the web interface at [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com/), as it is mentioned in the Google's [official FAQs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq) documentation.

Based on this, it seems that GCP doesn't offers a specific API alternative you can use to get synonyms; Therefore, I think you should try by using third-party software, such as [Datamuse API](https://www.datamuse.com/api/) or the libraries you mentioned before, to get the synonyms and then translate them by using the Google Translation API service as an available workaround.